# Preventing access directly to a PHP script

Tags: php

I have my .htaccess modded to remove the `.php` extension.

The following code I modded with `|| $parts['filename']` to not allow direct access. My goal is to prevent direct access for `/page.php` or `/page` However it's not working.

```
/***************DO NOT ALLOW DIRECT ACCESS************************************/
$parts = pathinfo(__FILE__);
if ( stripos( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], (basename( __FILE__ ) || $parts['filename'] )) !== FALSE ) { 
    header("Location: ./"); 
  die();
}
```

Code before mod prevent access to `/page.php` but **allows** access to `/page` (I don't want that)

```
/***************DO NOT ALLOW DIRECT ACCESS************************************/
if ( stripos( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) !== FALSE ) { 
    header("Location: ./"); 
  die();
}
```

How can I prevent access to both `/page.php` and `/page` ?

Comment: Can you just move page.php outside of the public root directory?

Comment: Rather just do it with code.

Comment: Check for the right `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, if you really want to do this from the .php file. That will hold the URL from where the user came. If it's empty or different than your site's URL, it's "direct access" as you call it :)

Comment: so, you want to be able to include the file from another script, but you don't want the file itself to be able to be served via the web server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to include the file from another script, but disallow direct serving via apache:

At the top of any php file you want to block direct access to:

```
<? __FILE__ != $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] || die('no direct access' );
```

---

Edit to include example

#### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

#### test.php

```
<?

header( 'content-type: text/plain');

var_dump( __FILE__ == $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );

include 'test-inc.php';
```

#### test-inc.php

```
<? __FILE__ != $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] || die('no direct access' );

var_dump( __FILE__ == $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
```

#### output for loading /test.php and /test

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

#### output for loading /test-inc.php and /test-inc

```
no direct access
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want page to be accessed do something like:

```
if(!defined("IN_SCRIPT")) die();
```

Make sure to define IN_SCRIPT in every script that'll include that file.

Software like phpBB also use this method.

Comment: This sounds like a very unmaintenable solution in my opinion. Why not just correct the htaccess rules so that neither page.php nor page can be accessed. Then all the logic is in one location.

Comment: he wants to prevent access to a directory, not the .php file

Comment: @thelolcat You say it's unmaintainable but actually a lot of scripts use this technique already.

Comment: That's a bad solution, he wants to prevent access to "folder" not file.

Comment: @user2854563: No he doesn't. He has used mod_rewrite so that the file can be accessed without the .php extension.

Comment: @user2854563 Read the question again, /page is pointing to /page.php which is a file...

Comment: @thelolcat He is trying to prevent access to the .php file, /page is being forwarded to that file.

Answer (score -1):

In your index put

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['logged'] = "OK";
```

then on every other file you want to validate include

```
session_start();
$login = isset($_SESSION["logged"]) ? $_SESSION["logged"] : false;
if($login != "OK"){
  header("Location: path/to/your/index");
  exit;    
}
```

Comment: @user2854563 he does not! Quote him on it!

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Using sessions would actually work for OP's case

Comment: Session must be started before you can use them. And there's nothing that suggests that the second script has to be included by the first, so that function would not be called twice

Comment: @onetrickpony The OP's code was trying to block the file based on it's name, so there aren't any other ways to run the script but to include it.